# RSAPrivateKeyImpl cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, jwt, rsa

I try to create JWTVerifier with RSA algorithm:

```
    JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.RSA512(rsaPublicKey, rsaPrivateKey)).build();
```

I want to create RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey instance with help their implementations RSAPublicKeyImpl and RSAPrivateKeyImpl and have problem with second instance, error context:

```
    'RSAPrivateKeyImpl(java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigInteger)' is not public in 
    'sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateKeyImpl'. Cannot be accessed from outside package.
```

Libraries:

```
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateKeyImpl;
import sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl;
```

Code in Intellij Idea:

```
    private RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey;
    private RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey;

    public JwtFilter() throws InvalidKeyException {
        this.rsaPublicKey = new RSAPublicKeyImpl(BigInteger.valueOf(1147), BigInteger.valueOf(7));
        this.rsaPrivateKey = new RSAPrivateKeyImpl(BigInteger.valueOf(1147), BigInteger.valueOf(463));
    }
```

RSAPublicKey is ok. Methods and classes are public. I cleaned and rebuilt my project, invalidated caches and restart.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your setup. Simply this constructor is not public so you cannot invoke it from classes in other packages. Also using classes  from `sun` packages is discouraged.

Comment: Ahh, ok, but how i can create two instance for Algorithm.RSA512(rsaPublicKey, rsaPrivateKey)? Create new classes which implements this interfaces?

Comment: Start by searching this site for other questions with your tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+jwt+rsa